# Google chrome; expanding div doesn't fully push footer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This error seems to only occur in Google chrome; when a div expands it only pushes parts of the footer down leaving a buggy-looking error;

I am sorry but i was unable to replicate the error in JSfiddle;

Can be found at http://stylrs.com/v1/contact2/

you can see a screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yiQD.png

Comment: When you submit the form for initial period, the right side form div overlaps with the footer. But After few seconds, it looks ok. Am I correct?

Comment: You do have some other problem, the 2 divs didn't contain into container div.

Comment: Yes but its still broken for quite a while; it satys broken if you dont move the browser; which is a shame since i need it on a different page

Comment: There are two empty <p> tags in your form that you can remove and also add the container div like @Gunaseelan specified